# Wordpress Gravity Forms Chained Selects Fields to php

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, pdf, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to reference 'chained selects' fields from the Wordpress Gravity Forms data into PDF. (I am following the developer tutorials at gravityPDF.) In the sample csv Gravity Forms provide for their 'Chained Selects' add-on, it has car 'Year' 'Make' and 'Model' with 3 form entry boxes each relying on the prior selection. This happens to be field number 4 on my form. The Gravity macro references these as Merge Tags in the following manner

```
 {cars (Year):4.1} {cars (Make):4.2} {cars (Model):4.3}
```

Normally for something like address it is simple to find the typical references required for php for example here they list several: https://gravitypdf.com/documentation/v4/developer-php-form-data-array/

There they show subfields for say address referenced as going from the merge tag refs on field 6:

```
{Business Address (Street Address):6.1}
{Business Address (Address Line 2):6.2}
{Business Address (City):6.3}
{Business Address (State / Province):6.4}
{Business Address (ZIP / Postal Code):6.5}
{Business Address (Country):6.6}
```

To this:

```
/* 6 is the ID of our field */
echo $form_data['field'][6]['street'];
echo $form_data['field'][6]['street2'];
echo $form_data['field'][6]['city'];
echo $form_data['field'][6]['state'];
echo $form_data['field'][6]['zip'];
echo $form_data['field'][6]['country'];
```

That all works fine but I don't understand where to define the equivalent of the 'street2' label for example in the array for the car data. If I try to copy the above theory I take this:

```
  {cars (Year):4.1} {cars (Make):4.2} {cars (Model):4.3}
```

to this:

```
<?php 
$f    = $form_data['field'];
$cars = $f[4];
$year = $f[4]['Year'];
$make = $f[4]['Make'];
$model = $f[4]['Model'];
?>

<?php echo $year; ?><br>
<?php echo $make; ?><br>
<?php echo $model; ?><br>
```

In the above I am effectively guessing the [street2] equivalent for this field ie where I have put ['Year'] ['Make'] ['Model'] and I get "Warning: Illegal string offset 'Year'" as a result in the pdf.

How and/or where do I define these labels? If looking at the ?data=1 method inside the pdf generated from Merge Tags as suggested here: https://gravitypdf.com/documentation/v4/developer-php-form-data-array/ then I only get to see for this field the following:

```
[4.cars] => Array
        [4] => Array
        [cars] => Array
```

I know it is a beginner question but am having tough time locating an answer. Thanks

Comment: Gravitypdf support says that $form_data does not support chained selects yet and that is being released in v5. Still looking to see if there is a way to echo these inputs in mean time using $entry

Comment: With today's update to Gravitypdf (4.4) which now supports 'chained selects' https://gravitypdf.com/news/gravity-pdf-4-4-released/ when I pull the data array out like this gravitypdf.com/documentation/v4/developer-php-form-data-array . It shows as [field] => array ( [1] => array ( [0] => 2015 [1] => Infiniti [2] => Q70)). So I can echo 'year' as $year = $form_data['field']['1']['0']; where 1 is the field reference on the form and 0 is first entry on chained select. Then 'Year is <?php echo $year; ?> now prints into the pdf.